# dropdown selectedindex change not working !! due to bootstrap

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, html.dropdownlistfor

Javascript console shows following error

> Uncaught TypeError: 
>   object is not a functionDefault4.aspx:28 
>   __doPostBackVM263:1 
>   (anonymous function)

When I tried same code on new blank form it works the page in which I'm trying has bootstrap included.

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dpdsizelist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dpdsizelist_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Have you got jquery loaded as well ?

Comment: yes yes   i m using jquery   <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.menu-aim.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>       these r 3 javascript i m using

Answer (score 0):

I got it it was my silly mistake i gave button id as "submit" that is causing issue then i renamed it to "btnsumbit" it was placed in master page.